# Put image in xhdpi but looks blurry

Tags: android, drawable, hdpi

I made rectangle drawable and put in drawable-xhdpi folder. But in my device it look blurry.
My device screen size is 1280x720 and density is 344 dpi. I put that xml file in all folders but still looks blurry. Please help me.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />

        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dip"
            android:color="#ADADAD" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

this is drawable that I put in drawable-xhdpi folder.

Comment: don't place it in drawable-xhdpi folder. just create a folder under /res named drawable and place it there.

Comment: not working. first I tried this.

Comment: @Dhiren can you check out my answeer.

Comment: Issue solved. I made o.5 to 1 dip.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create `rectangleimage.xml`and used this way.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
  <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>

</shape>
```

You have to put this `xml` to **res/drawable**

if you find any trouble then let me know.

Comment: I don't want rounded corner rectangle.